# Access outer class from inner Thread java

Tags: java, multithreading, class, outer-join

In a class OuterClass i have a Thread InnerThread. In the Thread i need to access a method from OuterClass. How do i do this? I tried :

```
public class OuterClass{

   public static void main(String[]args){
      Runnable thread = new innerThread(param);
        new Thread(thread).start();

   public void method(param1, param2){
      System.out.println("Test method");
   } 



   public class InnerThread extends Thread{
      public void run(){
         System.out.println("Test thread")
         OuterClass.this.method(param1, param2);
      }
   }

}
```

but the programm doesnt go into the method. Why is that and how could it work?

*edit* Im sure the Thread is running because I perform other actions there and they work, and I put a print right at the start of method(param1, param2), so i'm sure it doesn't enter the method. I tried only method(param1, param2) whithout OuterClass.this as well and it didn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean by it "doesn't go into the method"?  How have you determined that?

Comment: Are you actually starting the thread?

Comment: Just calling `method` should be fine unless you need to disambiguate. This question is not clear enough in its present form - please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Does the given code even compile? I see at least two problems: inconsistent capitalization and missing braces. Please provide us with some code that actually illustrates your issue and does not artificially introduce unrelated problems.

Comment: Also, the parameters for `method()` do not have any types...

Comment: @Code-Guru Not to mention unclassified and defined parameters and missing spaces

Comment: Please only post real code, else you don't have a real question.

Comment: Voting to delete. This question will not help future visitors to this site. Next time, please ask a better more complete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
public class OuterClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(new OuterClass().new InnerThread());
        t.start();
        t.join();
    }

    public void method(String param1, String param2) {
        System.out.println("Test method ("+param1+","+param2+")");
    }

    public class InnerThread extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Test thread");
            method("A", "B");
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
Test thread
Test method (A,B)
```

Comment: Yeah entering method() worked fine, there was a problem with the output, so i thought it didnt enter the method. My Bad.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating two separate classes
1 which contain OuterClass
2 Other which ctreate the instance of OuterClass i.e, main class.
Take a look.

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String arg[]){

OuterClass o=new OuterClass(1,3);
   }
    }

class OuterClass{
    int param,param2;
    InnerThread t;

OuterClass(int x,int y){
this.param=x;
this.param2=y;
InnerThread t=new InnerThread();
t.start();
}

 public class InnerThread extends Thread{
      public void run(){
         System.out.println("Test thread");
         OuterClass.this.method();
      }
   }
 public void method(){
      System.out.println(this.param+this.param2);
   }
}
```